# Separable non-linear ODE (with radicals)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to solve the equation

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\sqrt{\left(\gamma-1+\frac{2\alpha\beta}{2\alpha-1}\right)e^{-2\alpha y}-\frac{2\alpha\beta}{2\alpha-1}e^{-y}+1}\tag{1}
$$

$y(0) =  0$; $t_{0}=0$;  $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are positive constants ($\beta$ is also less than 1). There is also a special form for $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ but I will not dwell on this right now.

Provided I am not mistaken, letting $x = e^{-y}$ and rearranging leads to
$$
\int_{e^{-y(t)}}^{1}{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\left(\gamma-1+\frac{2 \alpha\beta}{2\alpha-1}\right)x^{2\alpha}-\frac{2 \alpha\beta}{2\alpha-1}x+1}}}=t\tag{2}
$$
This integral is solvable for particular values of $\alpha$ (ones that allow a partial fraction decomposition of the integrand(?))

**My questions are:**

1) Is there a relatively compact way that may determine if the
 integral $(2)$ can be expressed in closed form?

2) Can $x(t)$ be expressed in terms of relatively well-studied special
functions?

3) Even if a general method for solving this equation (which I believe
does not exist), is there a way of obtaining an approximate solution
for $x(t)$ in closed form?

I have considered taking the Taylor series of the radical, but unfortunately this method does not work very well because the integrand does contain a region of rapid change within the integration region.

Any ideas on how to treat this problem will be greatly appreciated!